# Squid - Allow local network to access specific websites

Tags: proxy, squid

Conf -

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager

acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain /etc/squid/whitelist.txt
http_access allow localnet allowed_http_sites
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
```

This doesn't work. I want my localnet to use only specific websites. I get a forbidden with above config.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed the double quotes in whitelisted sites ACL. Silly one. Anyway, below configuration just worked fine.

```
http_port 3128
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt"
http_access allow localnet allowed_http_sites
http_access deny all
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
```